# What materials are in Stack Exchange's diversity & inclusion training program?

Tags: discussion, community, code-of-conduct, diversity

Recently, Teresa Dietrich [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354978/196834) that:

> All members of the Community Team and selected members of the Public Platform Team have already taken 13 hours of Diversity & Inclusion Training. This training has been coordinated and advised by our own internal diversity & inclusion expert.

Can said team members, or others with appropriate access, share the materials from this training? It would be interesting to know what it includes.

> We’ve also been provided with resources for best practices in using pronouns and to help us better identify microaggressions specifically towards our LGBTQIA+ users.

Can we also be provided with (links to) these resources?

Comment: Teresa had said that she was open to the idea of sharing the LGBTQ+ specific resourced with the queer community members who were consulted before the Lavender Letter response post, so that they could provide feedback; I kinda doubt that it will be shared publicly, though.

Comment: If your goal was to get access to resources about diversity & inclusion training, then another idea would be to ask on IPS, but of course recommendations are [offtopic there](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/are-resource-recommendations-on-topic) like anywhere else. That would leave you with googling about it. I just did and found some free courses. I'm planning to take a few. If SE offers something, I will also look at them.

Comment: @Trilarion: No, I'm not looking for arbitrary resources, I'm interested in the resources and materials which SE inc. is training its staff with.

Comment: Okay. Then we are looking for different things.

Comment: Are diversity curricula typically confidential?

Comment: @Robert If you use an external commercial party to develop it, which you likely should as it's a difficult subject, then it's usual for it to be confidential, as it's that parties bread and butter to be able to sell such curricula.

Comment: @ErikA but would the confidentiality be limited to the pedagogical techniques used, or would it run to the very content of the curricula? There are quite a few proprietary reading curricula that schools and teachers can pay to use in their classrooms, but the underlying competency (how to read) in public domain and available to everyone who cares to spend the time to learn.