# How do I search for posts involving two users?

Tags: support, search, users

I want to find posts (on some specific SX site) in which each of two users either wrote the question or wrote an answer, i.e. both users interacted with the question in some way - either by authoring the question, writing an answer to it or a commenting on any post in the thread.

Is this possible?

Comment: Related: [Please give moderators better tools to understand the interactions between two users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334904/273494)

Comment: Use SEDE: [Have we met](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/25355/have-we-met)

Comment: I've tried to make it a little more clear what you're asking for - the meaning of the word "each" in context is sometimes tough for folks who aren't native English speakers. Feel free to adjust or rollback if I've misunderstood you.

Answer (score 10):

Well, @rene's suggestion is a workaround:

1. Visit: `https://data.stackexchange.com/SITENAME/query/25355/have-we-met` - replacing SITENAME with the name of the relevant site (no spaces nor hyphens; "stackoverflow" and "codereview" work for example)
2. Enter your own (numeric) user ID for that site.
3. Enter the other user's (numeric) ID for that site.
4. Run the query.

You'll get links and an explanation of how you interacted.

H-o-w-e-v-e-r - I still think I should be able to just search for that in the regular site search box.

Comment: No need to fiddle with the url: switch sites works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUODf.png